# Mic Recommendations for Hummingbird Chip Notes?

Tags: microphone, bird

I am doing my honors thesis on Anna's Hummingbird chip notes. I need to capture clean chip notes in the field. They are pretty distinct vocalizations, but part of my research is quantifying the duration of and intervals between each chip. So, I need the recording to have a minimal amount of artifacts/background noise/echo. What mics would be appropriate for this?

Comment: What is the frequency range of these notes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would agree with @WMXZ that it sounds like you would benefit from a parabolic mic.  Of these, the Telinga kit (https://www.telinga.com/) is often regarded to be the best, but is fairly expensive, and the Dodotronic equipment (https://www.dodotronic.com/product-category/parabolic-microphones/?v=2a47ad90f2ae) is also well regarded, but is cheaper.

Useful information on parabolic mics (and shotgun) is available at the Macaulay website, here: https://www.macaulaylibrary.org/resources/audio-recording-gear/microphones/

Answer (score 1):

In order to get good recordings (high signal to noise ratio), you want to reduce noise (ambient and interfering). You have, two methods:

- out-of-band noise: can 'easily' be removed by signal processing
- in-band noise: best method is to have directional sensors. I see three types of sensors,

  - directional (shotgun) microphones,
  - array of microphones,
  - single microphone with parabolic reflector.

The simplest method is the parabolic reflector and consequently very frequently used. You may consider the use of a windscreen to remove wind noise.

Sorry, I cannot advice on specific models and brand.